# JFreeChart and Time Series

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm creating a JFreechart which I want to feed 'real-time' dummy data every 5 or so seconds. This data is to represent some position of a vehicle relative to two ends (between 100 and 0). I'd like this positional data to be shown with the y-axis representing hours of the current day and the x-axis showing its position. Currently the positional data works fine and is added in 5 second intervals, however the x-axis (time) is displaying in seconds instead of hours.

EDIT: The x-axis has no range or ticks when using `((DateAxis)(domain)).setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.DAY, 1));`, it is just blank

```
public class DTSCTest extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final String TITLE = "Dynamic Series";
    private static final String START = "Start";
    private static final String STOP = "Stop";
    private static final int COUNT = 10;
    private static final int FAST = 5000;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private double gateStart = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 101);
    private boolean returning = false;
    private Timer timer;

    public DTSCTest(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =
                new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        Date date = new Date();
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(date));
        float[] gateStartLoad = new float[1];
        gateStartLoad[0] = (float)gateStart;
        dataset.addSeries(gateStartLoad, 0, "Longwall Data");
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I add my position values on the timer (5000 ms)

```
        timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {

            float[] newData = new float[1];

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(gateStart == 100){
                    returning = true;
                }else if(gateStart == 0){
                    returning = false;
                }
                if(returning){
                    gateStart--;
                }else{
                    gateStart++;
                }
                newData[0] = (float)gateStart;
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData);
            }
        });
    }
```

I then try to set the tick unit such that the x-axis displays hours of the day instead of each second of the day

```
    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", "Shearer Position", dataset, true, true, false);
        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(false);
        ((DateAxis)(domain)).setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.DAY, 1));
//        domain.setAutoRange(true);
        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(0, 100);
        return result;
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DTSCTest demo = new DTSCTest(TITLE);
                demo.pack();
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
                demo.setVisible(true);
                demo.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It seems that setting the tick unit myself does not affect the y-axis is anyway. How do I make it so that it displays hours of the current day instead of seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use a DateTickUnit constructor that allows to specify a
`DateFormat`
, and use a DateFormat with a suitable format string that includes the hours, such as "HH:mm:ss".